# Javascript prompt, display a message if answer is right

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So, I want to make a javascript bookmarklet that starts a prompt to type in a password. if the password is correct it will alert a secret message. I put together some code from my other bookmarklets, and made this:

```
javascript: prompt("Password?");if(12345) alert(Correct)
```

But alas, it doesn't work. The only javascript experience i have is tinkering a little with a bunch of bookmarklets so...

Comment: Try: `javascript:prompt("Password?")==12345&&alert("Correct")` but what is the use when the password (`12345`) is in there ?

Comment: try: `prompt("Password?") === 12345 ? alert("Correct") : ""`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for tinkering etc.  **It is not actually secure.**

```
let password = prompt('Password?');
if (password === 'asdf') {
  alert('correct');
}
```

W3schools has a good JavaScript intro series:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp